# Question not automatically protected

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, protected-questions

I direct your attention to this question: [How to import contacts from symbian mobile to android mobile?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10728/how-to-import-contacts-from-symbian-mobile-to-android-mobile)

It has, as of this moment, five deleted answers. All are of the "me too" or "thanks that worked!" variety.

And yet, the question isn't "Protected".

It was my understanding that if [a question gets three deleted answers from low-rep users attached to it, it automatically gets "Protected" status](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52765/21960) to help prevent these sorts of non-answer answers.

Did the automatic status change not happen? Or was it removed for some reason?

Comment: I protected it now, and based on the timeline it was not before. as you say.

Comment: The question remains, then: Why didn't it automatically happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I've figured it out, but I'd like some confirmation from Team Stack Overflow if possible.

Of the five deleted answers:

- one is from a fairly high-reputation user
- one is from a user who got the association bonus and so has 101 reputation points
- one is from a destroyed user account
- leaving two from low-reputation (10 or less) users

So that would seem to indicate that this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

---

sources:

- [Why wasn't this question automatically protected after 7 deleted spam answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114136/why-wasnt-this-question-automatically-protected-after-7-deleted-spam-answers)
- [Automatically protect questions with three or more low-rep-user deleted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89532/automatically-protect-questions-with-three-or-more-low-rep-user-deleted-answers)

Comment: Confirmed, only `n` from a "not new" user (10+ rep) count in the auto-protect feature.  I say `n` because it can vary by site, but is 3 everywhere currently.